# D-flex makes bootsrtap grid system broke

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, flexbox, react-bootstrap

I create a dashboard with reactJs and [react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/). Due to the different size of the card on my dashboard, it's resulting the gap on my dashboard. This is the screenshot :

[image: Gap on my dashboard webapp]

I want to fill the gap on my dashboard. According to the [bootstrap flex documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#align-items), I used `d-flex align-items-stretch` to fill the gap. Like this :

```
      <Row>
        <Col lg="6" md="6" sm="12" className="d-flex align-items-stretch"> //I placed it on Col
            <FrequentUsers />
        </Col>
        <Col lg="6" md="6" sm="12" className="d-flex align-items-stretch">
            //Other content
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

> Placing the `d-flex align-items-stretch` on the `<Col>` tag is the
> only way that I found worked in my case. If I place it in `<Row>` tag
> or in `<div>` tag as a container outside it, it didn't work.

The result is the y-axis stretched well as I expected, but the x-axis suddenly shrink :

[image: the card width suddenly shrink]

So I manage my grid layout to make it wider. The grid layout is still working but it didn't affecting the card, it is only affecting the gap like there is a invisible container in it. So I'm assuming that **the grid system at this point is "broken"**

I'm guessing that this is because the `d-flex`. But as I read the documentation, it should've instead make the content fully extended to the side. Please check it on the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors)

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Comment: @JanithaRasanga the code that I provide on Code Sample above is the actual code that I working in. Which part do you want to see more ?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `flex-basis` of the cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ChewySalmon's comment. I try to adjusting `flex-basis` on my card. The reason I do it directly on my card is because as I provided in a *code sample* in my question above, I *stretched* my item on a `<Col>` tag, which is stretch the conten **vertically** (as my screenshoot shown above). So I need to do it on my card **(also because this is the only way that worked in my case)**, so it stretched **horizontally**. And it work perfectly. Here is the implementation code :

```
<Card style={{flexBasis: "100em"}}> 
    //my content
<Card>
```

I use `100em` because it's the only way besides `100px` that worked for me. I hard coded it like that because the value is the same in all card, which is `100em`. But I recommend you using props in JSX attribute. Hope that help you who have a same problem with me in the future. Thanks to @ChewySalmon.